# Using CustomDictionary.xml in Visual Studio Code Analysis for fancy-cased identifiers

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, code-analysis, fxcop

For example, an identifier like `iPhone`.
When I ran code analysis, it gave me this error:

> CA1709 : Microsoft.Naming : Correct
>   the casing of 'i' in namespace name
>   'iPhone.Example' by changing it to
>   'I'.

I tried adding an entry to `CustomDictionary.xml` as follow:

```
<Words>
    <Recognized>
        <Word>iphone</Word>
    </Recognized>
</Words>
```

Then it still gave me the same error and one more, as follows:

> CA1702 : Microsoft.Naming : The
>   compound word 'iPhone' in namespace
>   name 'iPhone.Example' exists as a
>   discrete term. If your usage is
>   intended to be single word, case it as
>   'iphone'.

I then added some more rules as follows:

```
<Compound>
    <Term CompoundAlternate="IPhone">iphone</Term>
</Compound>
<DiscreteExceptions>
    <Term>iphone</Term>
</DiscreteExceptions>
<Acronyms>
    <CasingExceptions>
        <Acronym>iPhone</Acronym>
    </CasingExceptions>
</Acronyms>
```

But it didn't give any difference. Is there anyway to add this kind of exception?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nothing you add to the dictionary will avoid the original CA1709 violation since the problem has nothing to do with spelling.  Instead, it problem lies with the lack of capitalization of the first letter, which violates the Pascal casing convention for namespace names.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The dictionary also offers CasingExceptions column, so I think it should be able to handle more than just a spelling. So any idea how to do it without suppressing the error?

Comment: The CasingExceptions contents are used for other purposes (i.e.: distinguishing between the all-caps and pascal-cased portions of the CA1709 rule for 2 and 3 letter acronyms).  They are not consumed by the portion of the CA1709 rule logic that verifies that the first letter of a namespace name should be upper-case.

Comment: Okay, in that case there is really no way to do it. Thanks for taking time to answer it although it's not really the answer I'm looking for :-)